# Delete Rows from one table when specific columns are updated on other linked table - SQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `Seller` and another table `api_tokens`.
I want to remove all rows from `api_token` table of the seller when specific column `email/password` is updated from `Seller`.
`sellerId` is the foreign_key in `tokens` table. 
`userID` is the primary_key in `Seller` table.

I have tried to write a trigger but i am having a syntax error by phpMyadmin.

This is the code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
ON Seller
AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF UPDATE (email) 
  BEGIN
      DELETE a FROM api_tokens a
      INNER JOIN Seller s ON s.userID = a.sellerId
      Where UPDATED.userID = a.sellerId 
  END 
END
```

The trigger is not getting saved so i cannot conclude that this is working or not.

Getting syntax error by phpMyadmin but i cannot figure out what is the actual issue.

Sharing error details as well :

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON Seller

Comment: You are mixing MySQL and ms sql syntax. Pls refer to the MySQL manual on the correct MySQL syntax. Also, if a trigger does not refer to OLD or New, then most likely it is incorrect, since does not do anything related to the changed record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `updated`, you want `new`.

I also don't think the `join` is needed, just:

```
  DELETE a
      FROM api_tokens a
      WHERE NEW.userID = a.sellerId ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you mean MYSQL and Not MSSQL there are many parts that are only valid in mssql

If you still want mysql this works

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER UPDATE
ON Seller FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.email <> OLD.email then
          DELETE a FROM api_tokens a
          INNER JOIN Seller s ON s.userID = a.sellerId
          Where NEW.userID = a.sellerId ;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: No need for the join, just use the NEW.userid to delete from the api_tokens table.

Comment: Yes you are right we can remove the JOIN as well. Thanks @shadow.